# Identify html form or its encoding (text or file) in servlet

Tags: java, forms, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload, enctype

How do I recognize in a servlet whether the request sent using HTML form has enctype `multipart/form-data` or the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Alternatively: is there any other way to recognize which form was used? `request.getParameter("some_param")` works only with default encoding.

Comment: Just use `request.getPart("some_param")` or Apache Commons FileUpload. See also [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) Don't try to parse it yourself, for sure not if you're already asking trivial questions like this.

Comment: @BalusC It's better to ask than write something really wrong... I'm using Apache Commons FileUpload for multipart, but wasn't sure how to switch between handling multipart and default forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'm using Apache Commons FileUpload for multipart, but wasn't sure how to switch between handling multipart and default forms*

Use Apache Commons FileUpload's own [`ServletFileUpload#isMultipartContent()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html#isMultipartContent%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) to check it.

```
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
    // Parse with FileUpload.
}
else {
    // Use normal getParameter().
}
```

#### See also:

- [Apache Commons FileUpload User's Guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html)

Comment: Oh.. totally missed that after adding new html forms, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify using `Content-Type:` header

```
if(HttpServletRequest.getContentType().contains("form-data")){
   //handle multipart data
 ....
} else if(HttpServletRequest.getContentType().contains("x-www-form-urlencoded")){
   //handle from data
 ....
}
```

If the web container supports **Servlet 3.0, the use HttpServletRequest.getParts() API.**

```
if(request.getParts() !=null){
  //handle multipart
} else {
  //handle form data
}
```

Comment: Don't use `.contains()` when you should be using `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()`. In this case it's probably not a problem, but it's still sloppy.